# How can I generate random points in a given grid using the MATLAB rand function?

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to generate random points on a 18 by 16 grid with x ranging from -9 to 9  and y from -8 to 8.
  I have to do this by using the MATLAB rand function to generate two numbers
 ranging from 0 to 1 (one for the x and one for the y coordinate) and then scale it   up to the size of the grid. How do I go about doing that? I know that there are  easier ways to go about this, but this is how I have to do it.
Thank you!

Comment: This is really trivial, and has been asked before many times. What did you try? What reasearch did you do? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The following code helps you perform what you want

```
%% initialization

L=18; % Length of the grid
W=16; % Width of the grid
random_points=randi(2,L,W)-1; % generating random 0-1 on an L*W grid

%% plotting the random points on grid

for i=1:L
    for j=1:W
        if random_points(i,j)==1
            plot(i,j,'bo')
            hold on
        else
            plot(i,j,'r.')
            hold on
        end
    end
end
```

also an animation on how does the above code result in a random grid, can be created running the following code

```
%% initialization

L=18; % Length of the grid
W=16; % Width of the grid

%% generating and plotting the random points on the grid forever

while 1

random_points=randi(2,L,W)-1; % generating random 0-1 on an L*W grid
for i=1:L
    for j=1:W
        if random_points(i,j)==1
            plot(i,j,'bo')
            hold on
        else
            plot(i,j,'r.')
            hold on
        end
    end
end

pause(0.01)
hold off
end
```

p.s. if you want to stop the code from executing, just simply press **`Ctrl+C`** in **Command Window**.